# Как вставить на сайт картинку-обложку, встроенную в мп3-аудиофайл во время воспроизведения этого файла?

Tags: html, html5, веб-программирование, вёрстка, web-audio

Интересует вопрос - как отобразить на сайте картинку-обложку, встроенную в мп3-аудиофайл во время воспроизведения этого файла ориентировочно с помощью элемента аудио? Гуглёж ни к чему не привёл. За раннее спасибо.

Comment: Первый же ответ гугла: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881237/how-can-i-get-the-cover-of-an-mp3-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать библиотеку [JavaScript-ID3-Reader](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Музыка с обложкой</title>
<script src="id3-minimized.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<audio id=audio src="sound.mp3" controls></audio><br /><br />
<img id="picture" />
</center>
<script>
var url = audio.src;
ID3.loadTags(url, function() {
    var tags = ID3.getAllTags(url);
    var image = tags.picture;
    if (image) {
        var base64String = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < image.data.length; i++) base64String += String.fromCharCode(image.data[i]);
        picture.src = "data:" + image.format + ";base64," + window.btoa(base64String);
    }else{picture.style.display = "none"};
    },{
    tags: ["picture"]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

При чём, для этой цели из всей библиотеки достаточно одного файла **id3-minimized.js**