# Как получить обложку трека из ID3v2 mp3

Tags: javascript

Довольно долго искал информацию, как получить обложку из файла mp3 ID3v2, но увы так нечего и не нашел, библиотеки не хочу использовать, кто знает подскажите, хотя-бы статью как извлечь.

Comment: Эм, а что вы искали? https://mutagen-specs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/id3/id3v2.4.0-frames.html#attached-picture

Comment: Если без библиотек, то тогда смотрите как это реализовано в существующих [библиотеках](https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags).

Answer (score 0):

Ну если не использовать язык программирования, то просто надо вовспользоваться софтом.

Можно попробовать:

Mp3tag - программа для редактирования тегов файлов музыки, включая извлечение и вставку обложек.

TagScanner: тоже бесплатная, как программа выше. Тоже можно редактировать теги треков и с возможностью извлечения и добавления обложек.

Foobar2000 - медиаплеер. Можно открыть файл в плеере и потом через функцию "Copy artwork to clipboard" забрать обложку

Ещё есть EasyTAG, Kid3, MusicBrainz Picard и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Попадалось, но сам я это не пробовал - на PHP:

```html
class CMP3File { 
 var $title;var $artist;var $album;var $year;var $comment;var $genre; 
 function getid3 ($file) { 
  if (file_exists($file)) { 
   $id_start=filesize($file)-128; 
   $fp=fopen($file,"r"); 
   fseek($fp,$id_start); 
   $tag=fread($fp,3); 
   if ($tag == "TAG") { 
    $this->title=fread($fp,30); 
    $this->artist=fread($fp,30); 
    $this->album=fread($fp,30); 
    $this->year=fread($fp,4); 
    $this->comment=fread($fp,30); 
    $this->genre=fread($fp,1); 
    fclose($fp); 
    return true; 
   } else { 
    fclose($fp); 
    return false; 
   } 
  } else { return false; } 
 } 
}
```

Попробуйте перевести это на JavaScript. Но если всё же решите использовать библиотеку, [JavaScript-ID3-Reader
Public](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader)
 Вам в помощь. Ещё читайте тут: [Как вставить на сайт картинку-обложку, встроенную в мп3-аудиофайл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1393023/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BF3-%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80)